# Execute command against all files in folder

Tags: powershell, putty

I have a list of .pem files I want to convert to .ppk using `winscp.com`.

The command is:

```
WinSCP.com /keygen filename.pem /output=filename.ppk
```

How do write a script that will automatically read all *.pem files in the folder and convert them to ppk?

I presume I need to use this for a start

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include "*.pem" | % { & $_ }
```

But how do I capture filenames and make it so it will replace the lines in the command and process all dozens of pem files in a folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` is the PowerShell [call operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx). `$_` is an [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) holding the current object in a pipeline, in this case [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) objects. For this kind of object the expression `& $_` calls the default handler (the associated program) on the file, same as if you'd double-clicked the file in Explorer.

To get the code to do what you want you need to replace `$_` with your `winscp.com` statement and replace the filename literals with appropriate variables. Use `$_.FullName` for the full name of the file. Change the extension for the output file and put that path in a different variable.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include "*.pem" | % {
  $outfile = Join-Path $_.DirectoryName ($_.BaseName + '.ppk')
  & winscp.com /keygen $_.FullName "/output=$outfile"
}
```

Comment: works like a charm - thank you!
just added a variable to the winscp.com location and it converts
$scpfile

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the file name and full name. The difference is full name includes the complete path and name is just the file name.

```
 Get-ChildItem c:\users\somefolder -Recurse -filter "*.pem" | foreach{
   $name = $_.Name
   $fullName = $_.FullName
   Write-Output $name
   Write-Output $fullName
 }
```

If you run this you will understand. So you can get the name like this and then run any other command inside the foreach loop with the $name variable.

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this

```
$msbuild = "C:\pathofexefile\WinSCP.com"
$formatstring="/keygen {0} /output={1}.ppk"

Set-Location "c:\temp"

gci -file -Filter "*.txt"  | %{$arguments=($formatstring -f $_.FullName, $_.BaseName);start-process $msbuild $arguments  }
```